# Xpath webelement identfication in mozilla browser

Tags: selenium, xpath, mozilla

I am trying to identify a `WebElement` in Mozilla browser using the xpath.  Below is the html code:

```
<div id="address-book" class="grid-12" style="display:none;">
<!-- END ADDRESS BOOK -->
<!-- BEGIN PAYMENT OPTIONS -->
<div id="paymentSection" class="grid-12 form-section">
<div class="grid-contentx">
<div class="hd header-container">
<h3>Payment Information</h3>
</div>
</div>
<!-- BEGIN: CC FORMS -->
<div class="grid-6">
```

The relevant xpath I wrote in the page object factory is:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='paymentSection']/div[1]/div/h3")
private WebElement paysection;
```

Upon running the script, I am getting an error message "unable to identify the element".  Please help me if there is any correction to be done to the identified xpath.

Comment: Does `//div[@class="hd header-container"]/h3` work?

Comment: I am seeing three matching nodes for the below xpath                    //div[@class="hd header-container"]/h3

Comment: Ok, let's narrow it down to `//div[@class="grid-context"]/div[@class="hd header-container"]/h3`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many `xpaths` which can help you locate `h3` in the above case, let me list down a few :

using **id :**

```
xpath = "//div[@id='paymentSection']//h3"
```

using **text :**

```
xpath = "//h3[contains(.,'Payment Information')]"
```

using **class names :**

```
xpath = "//div[@id='paymentSection']//div[@class='hd header-container']/h3"
```

using combination of **id** and **class name :**

```
xpath = "//div[@id='paymentSection' and @class='grid-12 form-section']//h3"
```

Comment: I have tried with all the above options but still I am facing unable to locate the element error.Please help me out if there is any work around for the issue

Comment: I have not used the wait for the element as the page under which the application under test will be there for a while and has a good amount of time to identify the element.

Comment: I just rechecked and "//div[@id='paymentSection' and @class='grid-12 form-section']//h3" worked.Thanks for the help!